# ruby gtk installation problem on Fedora

Tags: ruby, user-interface, gtk

I recently wanted to install Ruby bindings for GTK on my Fedora 15 box. I installed all the packages with `yum` (`ruby-gtk2`, `ruby-gtk2-devel`, all that), and I get a NameError when trying to do a simple Hello World GUI app in Ruby. Here's the code:

```
require 'gtk'

window = Gtk::Window.new(Gtk::WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
button = Gtk::Button.new("Hello World")

window.set_title("Hello Ruby")
window.border_width(10)

# Connect the button to a callback.
button.signal_connect('clicked') { puts "Hello Ruby" }

# Connect the signals 'delete_event' and 'destroy'
window.signal_connect('delete_event') {
    puts "delete_event received"
    false
}
window.signal_connect('destroy') {
    puts "destroy event received"
    Gtk.main_quit
}

window.add button
window.show_all
Gtk.main
```

Comment: in `window = Gtk::Window.new`...

Comment: i still get this `gtk.rb:3: uninitialized constant Gtk::WINDOW_TOPLEVEL (NameError)` unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you want to pull in `gtk2` not `gtk` so change your `require` to this:

```
require 'gtk2'
```

Then, from the [fine manual](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3a%3aWindow#Gtk%3A%3AWindow.new):

> `Gtk::Window.new(type = Gtk::Window::TOPLEVEL)`
>
> Creates a new `Gtk::Window`, which is a toplevel window that can contain other widgets.

So you don't actually need to specify the `type` when you want a toplevel window but if you want to specify the `type`, then you want to use the `Gtk::Window::TOPLEVEL` constant not `Gtk::WINDOW_TOPLEVEL`:

```
window = Gtk::Window.new(Gtk::Window::TOP_LEVEL)
```

That pretty much exhausts my (current) knowledge of the Ruby Gtk bindings but hopefully it will get you moving the right direction.